# Execute two divs in same javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying fade effect in two different div classes at same same-time. For that i need two different scripts, and executing same script for two div(s), it lags. Is there any way to execute both divs in same script like 
(.fadein,.fadeo)? [FIDDLE- jsfiddle.net/562am/](http://jsfiddle.net/562am/).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> //Function 1
$(function(){
    $('.fadeo img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadeo :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadeo');}, 2000);
});
</script>

<script> //Function 2
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please note that the two languages are vastly different, and if you want to get good help by experts in the field of your question, you will want to be extremely careful with the tags you use. For instance, I am pretty darn good in Java, but I haven't the slightest clue as to what your problem may be, not the slightest. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. looking forward to help soon.

Comment: Do you want to achieve similar to this? http://jsfiddle.net/XVfMw/

Comment: Yes, quite similar to this. Like in this fiddle [jsfiddle.net/XVfMw](http://jsfiddle.net/XVfMw/) both the divs are coded in same function, can this be done in my function quoted in the question? so that both function 1 and 2 are combined. [jsfiddle.net/562am/](http://jsfiddle.net/562am/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you meant by combining the two into 1 function?

```
$(function(){
    var classes = ['.fadeo', '.fadein'];

    $.each(classes, function (index, elem){
        var selectorToHide = elem + ' img:gt(0)',
            selectorToFadeOut = elem + ' :first-child';

        $(selectorToHide).hide();
        setInterval(function() {
            $(selectorToFadeOut)
                .fadeOut()
                .next('img')
                .fadeIn()
                .end()
                .appendTo(elem);
            }, 
            2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

2 setInterval run on their own - they may produce lags. The correct way is to use 1 interval and do the whole logic there.
With appendTo you're changing the DOM every 2 seconds. This method causes extra performance issues and leads to slower application run. I would suggest you to keep an index with the current image, and change it as you want (this is shown below).
In my example I've calculated the minimum number of images (if separate divs have different image count).

```
$(function () {
    // a value can be fixed - a constant 
    var imagesCount = Math.min($('.fadeo > img').size(),
                           $('.fadein > img').size());
    var i = 0;
    display(i);
    setInterval(function () {
        i = (i+1) % imagesCount;
        display(i);
    }, 2000);
});

function display(nth) {
    $('.fadeo > img').hide().eq(nth).show();
    $('.fadein > img').hide().eq(nth).show();    
}
```